# Calling Sharepoint Online API using Azure AD Registered App

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-ad, authorization, azure-active-directory

I registered an app in Azure Active Directory and granted several privileges:

[image]

Then I got myself a bearer token by calling:

```
 https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

with the scope:

```
 https://{tenantName}.sharepoint.com/.default
```

When I use that token to make an API call like:

```
https://infoinnobake.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:STS_Site contentclass:SP.Webb'&selectproperties='Title,Path'&rowlimit=500`
```

I only reveice `401 Unsupported app only token.`

can some explain why?

Is it possible to access the SharePoint online API with an registered App on Azure AD?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-api-secured-with-aad), [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread) and [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient)?

Comment: @GaneshSanap many thanks! You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @GaneshSanap for providing me a solution.
You need to create a self signed cert and upload it to the registered app in AAD.
Follow this guide to do so:

[Granting access via Azure AD App-Only](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread).

Comment: to clarify - secrets don't work, only certificates?

Comment: @Fowl this is how I usually do it: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs it works with secret

Answer (score 1):

In Order to call SharePoint Online API using Azure AD Registered App, you need to Set up an Azure AD app for app-only access and grant the permissions to it.

Please read below article for more clarification:

[Granting access via Azure AD App-Only](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread).

**Additional References**:

1. [Connect to API secured with Azure Active Directory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-api-secured-with-aad).
2. [Connect to Azure AD-secured APIs in SharePoint Framework solutions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient).